# quality difference in models

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, objects, shaders

As you can see, the main car to the left (Porsche) looks great, but the other cars look so wierd compared to it. I still want the porsche to look the best, but the others not to look so crappy
Beginner here, any advice or tutorial would help.[image]

Comment: first off I may be wrong but there doesn't seem to be a lot of reflection on your yellow car (and no trasnparency for the glasses), maybe give it a metal material?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1pklYZN

I guess its a bit better, but what about lighting/shading?

Comment: Yes there should be a shadow under your car, have you checked the Shadow option of the light?

Comment: It seems that was the problem, the hdri light and scene lights. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Increase the *Metallic* value up to 1 for the car, give reflexion to its glass, enable the *Shadow* and *Contact Shadows* options of your lights.